# Error when update a content in ektron

Tags: api, ektron

I have an *ektron8.7* application in which I'm trying to update a content. (I'm trying to make a content deleted by setting its ExpireDate)

```
        Dim contentItem As ContentData = contentApi.GetItem(contentId)
        contentItem.ExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        contentApi.Update(contentItem)
```

I am getting the following exception here

```
http://MyPC:8732/Ektron.ASM.EktronServices/CmsHelperService2.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details
```

and the InnerException is,

```
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it MyIP:8732"
```

My website was *upgraded from ektron 8.0 to 8.7*

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: That error does not appear to be related- does it occur if you remove those lines of code? Also, why not just use the API's delete method?

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? Is this a 3-tier application?

Comment: No.. its a 2-tier application

Comment: Can you try setting a hosts entry for 127.0.0.1 MyPC? I assume MyPC is your local machine and your Ektron instance is running locally as well. It may be that the server is trying to access itself and failing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your EktronWindowsService40 is running on your machine; that port 8732 indicates that the server is trying to send data to the service (which handles go live and expiration dates).  If that is not running it won't be able to complete your request.

If it is running, make sure that the name 'MyPC' resolves to the address of the machine running the site.

If all else fails, check your Event Viewer, under 'Applications and Services log' - there is an event log called 'EktronL4' which is used by the Ektron Windows Service to log errors.  If there are any entries besides 'Service Initialized Successfully', and 'Service Started Successfully' after starting the service, there is a problem with the service itself.  At that point, call Ektron Support.